# How to properly store variables to use with parfor?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

My calculations are based on a binary tree, which takes two previous instances of a block of variables (called Assemblies) and produces another one.
A new assembly is generated based on two assemblies from the upper branch, so all variables must be stored.

To this end, I use cell arrays with the following syntax: `Assembly_ij = Tree{ithBranch}{jthAssembly}`, where `Assembly` is a `18x3 double` Matrix. This approach is [allowed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/sliced-variable.html) by Matlab, however, it doesn't improve the execution of the code at all. 
I believe this is due to the inappropriate way in which I pass variables to workers. I get the following warning:

> The entire array or structure 'Tree' is a broadcast variable. This
>   might result in unnecessary communication overhead.

Most work is done in this part of code, and it should convey the mistake I am making.

```
initialBranch = initialize();
Tree{1} = initialBranch;
for i = 2 : Nbranches
    branch = cell(1, elmsInBranch(i));
    parfor j = 1 : elmsInBranch(i)
        branch{j} = assembleBlocks(Tree{i-1}{2*j-1}, Tree{i-1}{2*j});
    end
    Tree{i} = branch;
end
```

Matlab must surely pass the whole Tree structure to each worker, which is a lot of useless copying. I have no idea how to rewrite it to make it work properly, however, maybe **there is some clever way to extract just the needed variables for each worker**?

Comment: Did you try assigning `previous_branch = Tree{i-1}`, and using that variable inside the `parfor` loop?

Comment: Even if matlab would accept above modelling, it does not really use the locality of your problem. Assuming you have 4 workers. From the 3rd level on, each of the workers could complete 1/4 of the tree without talking to any other worker. Only at the end, the whole tree would have to be put together. Obviously more challenging to implement, but might be worth it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're passing the entire `Tree{i-1}` variable into each (parallel) iteration of the `parfor` loop. This is because the MATLAB interpreter isn't "clever" enough to work out which parts of `Tree{i-1}` you will need because you're dynamically indexing into it with some calculation based on `j`.

Assigning a temp variable in the outer loop, which can be directly indexed with `j` within the inner loop, should resolve this:

```
initialBranch = initialize();
Tree{1} = initialBranch;
for i = 2 : Nbranches
    N = elmsInBranch(i);
    branch = cell(1, N);
    % Pre-partition the data to send individual packets to each node 
    iTrees = arrayfun( @(j) Tree{i-1}([2*j-1,2*j]), 1:N, 'uni', 0 );
    % Parallel loop...
    parfor j = 1 : N
        jTrees = iTrees{j}; % direct indexing using 'j', no calculation      
        branch{j} = assembleBlocks(jTrees{1}, jTrees{2});
    end
    Tree{i} = branch;
end
```

Note that the `cellfun` I've added partitions your data so that each parallel node can directly index one element at a time, which contains both `Tree` items required within the loop. This may cause duplication in memory, but less duplication than broadcasting the entire array to every node!

Comment: Nice solution! The local copy of `iTrees`, being a cell array, would just point to the same data matrices that are in `Tree`, so no excessive memory usage.

Comment: @Cris they can't be stored by reference internally though, as a change to `iTrees` would not affect `Tree`? And each node gets "sent" its own elements... Or is that allocated as required?

Comment: MATLAB does lazy copying, I'm sure you are aware. That means that `b=a` doesn't make a copy of `a` until you modify one of the two variables. The arrays in `iTrees` would point at the same data as the arrays in `Tree`, until modified.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I see how this should work, however, the code crashes at the `cellfun` line. I get `Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was double.` I simply used anonymous function instead: `iTrees = @(j) AsmTree{i-1}([2*j-1,2*j])`. This made the warnings disappear, however, the improvement in speed isn't satisfying :( The sequential program evaluates in 0.9 seconds, whereas for my initial approach it took 9 whole seconds. Now, with your fixes, it's about 6 seconds.

Comment: @Maverick Sorry, that should have been an `arrayfun` - I've edited my answer. Worth noting that 0.9secs is not a long execution time, there will always be overhead communicating with the parallel workers, and I'd be mildly surprised if you saw a reduction below 0.9 secs. Often the key is to optimise your code further rather than throwing a `parfor` at it.

Comment: @Wolfie You are probably right, however, I had done the same implementation in c++ openMP, where all parallel regions were just `for` loops. The improvement in the execution time was about 2x.